# Need to access useState value within a useEffect, but cant put it in dependency arr because socket.io

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, react-hooks

I have a socket emitting from the server that sends a +1 or -1. The socket.on must be in a useEffect or else the socket gets called twice. I can't just put the number const in the dependency array becuase each time the socket is called it would chain every previous call, taking longer each time.
**So how can I update the number using the socket?**

```
function test() {
    const [number, setNumber]= useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('numChange', function(data) {
            let newNum = number + data;
            setNumber(newNum)
            console.log(number)
        });
    }, [socket])

    return (
    <main>
        {number}
    </main>
)}
```

This is a simplified snippet of my actual problem. The socket is created in a global context. The one solution I got to work was to store the number value in local storage and retrieve it within the socket.on function, but it wasn't a solution that worked for all my use cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't explain why it works but I think I've found the solution I've been looking for

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('numChange', function(data) {
        setNumber(number => number + data);
    });
}, [socket]);
```

found solution by cross referencing  [this repo](https://github.com/adrianhajdin/project_chat_application) in Chat.js

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing `socket` from dependency array? Ideally you should set up one socket handler, that too on mount only.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('numChange', function(data) {
        let newNum = number + data;
        setNumber(newNum)
        console.log(number)
    });
}, [])
```

Comment: Having an empty dependency has the same results as having socket in it, and removing the array entirely has the same results as putting number in the array.